# SQL Server 2012 Mirror in a Disconnected state - how do I fix it?

Tags: sql-server-2012, mirroring

We had a hardware failure last night and we got our servers up and running.  After logging into SSMS I find all the mirrored databases in a disconnected state.  I've done some searching with google-fu, but I've not found what I need.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Edit#1

I broke the mirror and attempted to reconfigure it through the wizard. Once I "Finish" it looked like it was going to work, then it failed with the following error:

> The server network address "TCP://SeanServer00.DBA.com:5022" can not
>   be reached or does not exist. Check the network address name and that
>   the ports for the local and remote endpoints are operational.
>   (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 1418)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, everything stayed the same, I found out that the service account **some how** lost the `CONNECT` permission.

So, I gave the service accounts the `CONNECT` permission and all the mirrored database synced as expected!